# Definition of Dedekind-infinity: Bijection or Injections?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been using the following definition of infinity (from Dedekind):

Set $S$ is infinite iff there exists a proper subset $S'$ of $S$ and *bijection* $f: S\rightarrow S'$.

Occasionally, I have seen "injection" used instead of "bijection." Exactly why is this wrong? Can anyone give me a counterexample demonstrating why these are not equivalent definitions?

---

**Follow-up 8 years later: See my formal proof of the equivalence using a form of natural deduction and basic set theory at:** http://dcproof.com/DedekindEquivalentDefinitions.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditions are equivalent (without use of the Axiom of Choice): Suppose $S$ contains a proper subset $S'$ with a bijection $f:S\to S'$. This is in particular an injection.

In the other direction, suppose $S$ contains a proper subset $S'$ with an injection $g:S\to S'$. There is clearly also an injection $h:S'\to S$ (simply the inclusion function) and thus, buy the Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein Theorem (which does not require the Axiom of Choice), there is a bijection $f:S\to S'$.

Thus, the condition for Dedekind finiteness can be stated in terms of an injection or a bijection from the set to a proper subset. The two are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent. One direction is clear: a bijection $f$ from $S$ to a proper subset of $S$ **is** an injection from $S$ to a proper subset of $S$. In the other direction, an injection $f:S\to S'$, where $S'\subsetneqq S$, is a bijection from $S$ to $f[S]\subseteq S'\subsetneqq S$, so $f$ is a bijection from $S$ to a proper subset of $S$.

Note, however, that this is **not** the usual definition of *infinite set*. According to the usual definition, an infinite set is one that does not admit a bijection to any finite ordinal, i.e., to any set of the form $\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$. Sets with your property are [*Dedekind-infinite*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set) sets. It is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there be infinite sets that are Dedekind-finite, i.e., that do not admit a bijection to any finite ordinal or to any proper subset.

Answer (score 1):

Note that every function is onto its range (not codomain!), so if there is an injection into a proper subset then there is a bijection with a proper subset, which is the range of the injection.